# Ruby overload + operator

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

What is the right way to overload operators in ruby?
What do I need to do to redefine how + works?
This function isn't being called when the + operator is used.

```
def +(a,b)
 return a * b
end

p 2 + 2
```

Comment: `2 + 2` is not a good example to test the difference between `+` and `*`

Comment: I was only trying to show that I wanted to change the behaviour of +. I was trying to figure out how to land in that +(a,b) function. All I was attempting to get was anything besides 4 from 2 + 2.

Comment: Just curious: what made you think `+` has two parameters? To me, it seems blindingly obvious that it should have only one: it's a binary operator, after all, and binary operators have two operands, which is why they are called "binary" operators. The first operand is `self`, obviously, since Ruby is an OO language, and so there can only be one other argument. Plus, of course, the documentation or `+` only ever lists a single argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloaded operator is resolved based on the class of the first operand, so if you wanted to overload the addition of simple integers, something like that should work:

```
class Fixnum
  def +(other)
    return self * other
  end
end
```

I do not recommend you to actually do this, btw.

Comment: I don't plan on actually using this for anything. I just didn't understand that it's resolved based on first class. I just arbitrarily picked + and *. Once I saw that 2 + 2 didn't equal 4 I knew I succeeded, and I threw away the code.